# SQL Sorting of Grouped Data

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm looking for a way to return data in a very specific order from an Access database using SQL. I want look for the lowest frequency, list all systems in frequency order starting with the system of the lowest frequency, then do the same operation on the next highest frequency and so on.

This is how I would like the output to be. (The line breaks are just for ease of seeing the sort order, I will add those in the program code later.)

```
System   Freq
------  ------
FM        100
FM        120
FM        150

AM        110
AM        150
AM        170

CW        160
CW        180
CW        200
```

Is something like this possible with SQL? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the source? Is the example you provided final output or is this the source?

Comment: Freq is computed from a aggregate function such as `SUM` or `AVG` isn't it?

Comment: This is how I would like the sort to work. I didn't show it in this example but a normal ORDER BY does not work because the System column is not in alphabetical order but I want the System names to stay together and as a group get sorted by frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Select System, Freq
from YourTableName
Order By System, Freq
```

Or if I 're-read' your question correctly probably this is what you want (apologies for a very back of envelop code)

```
Select  YT1.[System], YT1.[Freq]
From    YourTable YT1
        Inner Join (
            Select [System], Min(Freq) MinFreq
            From    YourTable YT2
            Group By [System]
        ) YT3 on YT1.[System] = YT3.[System]
Order By YT3.[MinFreq], YT1.[System], YT1.Freq
```

Comment: That looks like it will do what I'm trying to do. However when I try that out on my database I get the error YT1.[System] has no default value. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dan If you can post your [YourTable] structure it would be simpler to answer this. Does YT1.[System] has nulls or are you using this as sub query to insert into another table?

Comment: Turns out I should have been referencing he index instead of another joined column. It works great now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

General answer is yes, give an alias for your Freq computed column and order by both System and Freq: See an example for multiple row sorting [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19797).

Answer (score -1):

Without a clearer picture of your source data, this looks like it's just a simple order by on multiple columns:

```
SELECT [System], [Freq]
FROM [TableName]
ORDER BY [Freq], [System]
```